# Use regexprep with cell array for colons to format

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, regexp-replace

I have a cell array formatted as:

```
t = {'23:34:22.959511';
     '22:34:11.885113';
     '12:34:08.995146';
     '11:34:02.383092'}
```

I am trying to format the output as 4 column vectors as:

```
a = 23
    22
    12
    11

b = 34
    34
    34
    34

c = 22
    11
    08
    02

d = 959511
    885113
    995146
    383092
```

I am using `regexprep` to operate on the data:

```
a = regexprep(t,':34:22.959511', '')
```

However this only pertains to only one string in the data set and not all strings.

How do I divide the string into 4 column vectors -- using `regexprep` for colon: and display the output below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're willing to use other solutions that regexp: [`strplit`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) can split on any desired character:

```
a = zeros(numel(t),1);
b = zeros(numel(t),1);
c = zeros(numel(t),1);
d = zeros(numel(t),1);

for ii = 1:numel(t)
    C = strsplit(t{ii}, ':');
    a(ii) = str2double(C{1});
    b(ii) = str2double(C{2});
    tmp = strsplit(C{3},'.'); % Additional split for dot
    c(ii) = str2double(tmp{1});
    d(ii) = str2double(tmp{2});
end
```

Of course this only works when your data always has this structure (two colons, then one dot)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way:

```
r = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(t, ':|\.', 'split'), 'uniformoutput', false));
```

This gives

```
r =
          23          34          22      959511
          22          34          11      885113
          12          34           8      995146
          11          34           2      383092
```

If you really need four separate variables, you can use:

```
r = num2cell(r,1);
[a, b, c, d] = r{:};
```

Comment: To speed up getting the four variables, wouldn't it be faster to not convert your first line for `r` to a matrix, but use the cell directly? So instead of `num2cell(cell2mat(cellfun(..)))` directly do `cellfun(..)`, or are the dimensions/elements then in a wrong order?

Comment: @Adriaan Yes, the dimensions would be in the wrong order. We need to transpose them. That is essentially what `cell2mat` and `num2cell`do: `cell2mat` converts to matrix, and `num2cell` extracts its colums

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using split instead of strsplit. split will operate on vectors and if you use the string datatype you can just call double on the string to get the numeric value

```
>> profFunc
Adriaan's Solution: 5.299892
Luis Mendo's Solution: 3.449811
My Solution: 0.094535

 function profFunc()

    n = 1e4; % Loop to get measurable timings

    t = ["23:34:22.959511";
         "22:34:11.885113";
         "12:34:08.995146";
         "11:34:02.383092"];

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        a = zeros(numel(t),1);
        b = zeros(numel(t),1);
        c = zeros(numel(t),1);
        d = zeros(numel(t),1);

        for ii = 1:numel(t)
            C = strsplit(t{ii}, ':');
            a(ii) = str2double(C{1});
            b(ii) = str2double(C{2});
            tmp = strsplit(C{3},'.'); % Additional split for dot
            c(ii) = str2double(tmp{1});
            d(ii) = str2double(tmp{2});
        end
    end
    fprintf('Adriaan''s Solution: %f\n',toc);

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        r = cell2mat(cellfun(@str2double, regexp(t, ':|\.', 'split'), 'uniformoutput', false));
        r = num2cell(r,1);
       [a, b, c, d] = r{:};
    end
    fprintf('Luis Mendo''s Solution: %f\n',toc);

    tic
    for i = 1:n
        x = split(t,[":" "."]);
        x = double(x);

        a = x(:,1);
        b = x(:,2);
        c = x(:,3);
        d = x(:,4);
    end
    fprintf('My Solution: %f\n',toc);
```